# searching for character occueances in a line within a file in Linux and editing it

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, scripting, delimiter

I have a delimited fields file that I want to load into the database in Linux. The thing is that the number of delimited fields is not the same in every row. So, I need a shell script to iterate over each line and check for the number of occurrences of the delimiter character, I need 13 occurrences of the delimiter character per line. So, if I have 10 for example, I need to add 2 extra delimiter characters at the end of this line.

Now all that I have got is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while read p; do
  if
  -----------
  fi
done <myDataFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information provided is rather sparse.

What's your delimiter?

Can the delimiter (quoted) occur in any of the fields?

For a simple case, e.g. delimiter="|" and doesn't occur inside the fields here's a quick `awk` hack.

```
$ cat myDataFile 
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|m
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|c|d|e|f|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
```

And the awk:

```
awk -F'|' '{missing=13-NF;if(missing==0){print $0}else{printf "%s",$0;for(i=1;i<=missing-1;i++){printf "|"};print "|"}}' myDataFile 
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|m|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|c|d|e|f|i|j|k|l|m||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
```

And the awk made pretty and explained:

```
{
        missing = 13 - NF      # store the number of missing fields
        if (missing == 0) {    # if all fields are present
                print $0       # just print the line 
        } else {               # otherwise
                printf "%s", $0        # first print the line
                for (i = 1; i <= missing - 1; i++) {   # then pad the line with delimiters (w/o a newline)
                        printf "|"                     
                }
                print "|"      # followed by a last one WITH a newline                     
        }
}
```

Comment: YESSS I am using "|" as a delimiter. AND YOU HAVE JUST SAVED MY LIFE. THANK YOU SO MUCH !! :D

Comment: Heh. Glad that worked for you :)  As a rule of thumb:  it's rarely a good idea to use bash to iterate over lines of text-files, `awk` (`perl`, `python`, ... ) are much better choices.  Did the explained awk program make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, you have explained it very well :) ! I am a bit familiar with awk but I never used a loop in it.

Comment: Hello @tink .. I have a similar issue this time. I need to cover both conditions:                1 - if the fields are more than 13..                                                                                     2- if the fields are less than 13. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Maybe? :)  If you write a new question, this time adding sample data?  ;) @MinaEl-Raheb

Comment: @MinaEl-Raheb - what do you want to happen when there are more than 13? Trim the line? Pad the others to match the longest?

Comment: Hi @tink

I need 14 columns this time so I applied : 
awk -F'|' '{missing=14-NF;if(missing==0){print $0}else{printf "%s",$0;for(i=1;i<=missing-1;i++){printf "|"};print "|"}}' myDataFile 

Suppose I have a row like that: 
a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i|


after applying the awk command it will be:
a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i||

and this is not acceptable I need the data to be 14 columns only.

Answer (score 0):

```
{m,g}awk NF=13 FS='[|]' OFS='|'

a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|m|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
a|b|c|d|e|f|i|j|k|l|m||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
```